# How to bubble sort in Bourne Shell?

Tags: linux, shell, sh, bubble-sort

I have an assignment with the following requirements:

> Make Bourne Shell program using bubble sort algorithm to sort numbers given by user into the ascending order.
> Program asks first numbers of elements to sort and then asks those numbers one by one.

I can do this with `bash` but `sh` has no arrays.

I've included the most recent piece of code that I feel was on the right track to solving this. I have newer code but it presented many more problems.

```
#!/bin/sh

## Shifts values for $1 and $2 through all arguments
## For arguments (9 7 2 5 9) the end result is (7 2)
 
bubble_sort ()
{  
    set -- $1
    for i in $(seq 1 $#)
    do
        for j in $(seq 0 $(($# - ${i} - 1)))
        do
            # Needed so first number isn't ignored
            if [ $j -gt 0 ]; then
                shift 1
            fi
            # swap
            if [ $1 -gt $2 ]
            then
                #temp=$1
                #$1=$2
                #$2=$temp
            fi
        done
    done
}
 
read -p "How many values do you wish to sort? " amount_of_numbers_to_sort
 
for i in $(seq 1 ${amount_of_numbers_to_sort})
do
    read -p "Give number ${i}: " nth_number
    unsorted_numbers="${unsorted_numbers} ${nth_number}" 
done
 
bubble_sort "${unsorted_numbers}"
 
echo $temporary_list
```

I can't figure out how to get the value for the last argument. I tried adding a temp variable to hold the values of a new list of numbers but each iteration came out wrong.

### How can I move forward?

This is a basic Linux course that isn't about scripting, rather, history of Unix, GUI, etc.

My only thoughts are to write my own 'array function' which is probably extremely difficult. Or to some how recursively call my function. Any better ideas would be appreciated, thanks for reading!

Comment: Such a big wall of text! Do you think people will read it? Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to concentrate on `Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague` part. `First that was` Do not post links to external sites. Include code as text inside your question.

Comment: Instead of an array, use a set of variables `val1`, `val2`, `val3`, etc and dynamically set/get them using `export` and `eval`

Comment: `shift $(($# - $(($# - 1)) ))` Weeell, that's equal to `$# - ($# - 1)` so it's just `1`.

Comment: (aside: `/bin/sh` hasn't been Bourne on modern systems for decades now; it's POSIX sh these days -- the way autoconf distinguished the two when I started in the 90s was to run `echo hello ^ cat`; if it emits `hello` it's 1970s Bourne, if it emits `hello ^ cat` it's POSIX).

Comment: @thatotherguy Please post that as an answer. It helped simplify my code and finish the script.

Answer (score 0):

> how to get the value for the last argument

```
last_arg() {
   if [ $# -gt 1 ]; then
      shift $(($# - 1))
   fi
   echo "$1"
}

func() {
    last_argument=$(last_arg "$@")
}
```

I.e. create a function to do the stuff with arguments that you want to do. Inside that function, you have a fresh `$@` that you can do what you want without affecting parent function.

> How can I move forward?

The inner part starting from `if [ $j -gt 0 ]; then` is rather odd. You have to implement `swap`.